# SP Online: how to include managed property in list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property

Sharepoint Newbie here...
Our company has a OOTB SP Online site which we use mainly as a document repository. 
I used the SP Migration Tool to migrate data from an internal file server to sharepoint, but when viewing a folder and its contents in a standard SP List web part, the "Modified" date does not match the modified timestamp on the fileserver.  The following blog post does a good job of explaining the full scenario:
https://uscatu.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/file-modified-date-misalignment-in-sharepoint-explorer-view-and-file-sharesdrives/

I followed the above post and mapped the crawled properties to the managed property RefinableDate00 as described, but then I still can't reference this newly mapped "column" in my list results.

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help, Phil.

Answer (score 1):

After updating the Managed property, we need to execute the full crawl to update. Since the environment is SharePoint Online, we need to wait up to 24 hours to update automatically in SharePoint Online background.

Comment: Thank you, HelloFiona_MSFT for the information. When I use the search query tool I can see the property populated with data. My question is how to be able to select that as a column when modifying a view? This still does not show up in the list of available columns. Sorry, but as I said, I am a SP Newbie. Thanks again.